# Can a dynamic library reference Objective-C objects and still be unloaded?

Tags: objective-c, c, dynamic-linking

I know that, at least on OS X, due to the way classes are loaded by Apple's Objective-C runtime it is not possible to dynamically unload a dynamic library that contains the implementations of a loaded class. Does this hold true for a library that only knows about objects from referencing a header, but does not contain the method implementations of any class?

For clarity, I'd like to use Objective-C to write the dynamic library, but would load and unload functions with signatures like `ResultObject* performActionOnObject(SomeObject* object)`.

Edit:

For more clarity, consider a function like

```
NSNumber* computeFactorial(NSNumber* operand){
  NSUInteger n = [operand unsignedIntegerValue];
  /// ... pure C loop omitted
  return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:n];
}
```

And assume when it is called an autorelease pool is active. Would that be okay to unload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the client references your class directly, it will result in a linker error if the class is not in a linked binary. You could load/unload classes at runtime, but you would need to look them up by their names (strings) to use them. You will also need to register the class(es) before you look them up by name.

You can pass C functions to runtime calls like `class_addMethod` and `method_exchangeImplementations` to extend/alter your ObjC class at runtime.

Googling "method swizzling" will lead you to examples.

So ultimately… "It depends on how you interface with the object".

Comment: I think you indirectly answered me, but I don't want to load or unload any classes. I don't even want to dynamically add methods to classes. I just want to load and unload functions that have operands and return values which are Objective-C objects. If I read you correctly that shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: @LoyalTingley No, just think of them as if they returned `void *` or `id`. Their type signature does not really matter.

Comment: @LoyalTingley it will work, but there are some things you cannot do without its symbols (e.g. `[MONClass alloc]`) -- the linker will tell you if this happens. But no, the class symbols aren't typically required for functions.

Comment: @justin so message sending should work with the function arguments, but any classes I would have to resolve with `NSClassFromString`? So for my `NSNumber` edit I would have to revise so that it doesn't need the class symbol for the return line?

Comment: @LoyalTingley yes, you can unload that -- `NSNumber` is exported by CoreFoundation.

Comment: @justin you have confirmed my thoughts, and I hadn't even considered class symbol problems in the dylib until you mentioned it. Thank you very much.